# how to find id of the clicked element in a document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my html and i want to find the id of clicked element to be id3. however the code loops through parent divs too returning id=d3 on 1st iteration and id="id1" in 3rd iteration. is there a way to stop the iteration after 1st result of id="id3

```
<div id="d1">
    <div id="id2">
        <div id="id3">Click me</div>
    </div>
</div>

var ij=1
$(document).on('click','div', function(e){
    var currentID = this.id; 
    console.log("ij="+ij+" You clicked the element ="+currentID);
    ij+=1
});
```

Comment: `e.stopPropagation()`

Comment: `e.stopPropagation();` Try this

Answer (score 5):

You need [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

> Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```js
var ij = 1
$(document).on('click', 'div', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var currentID = this.id;
  console.log("ij=" + ij + " You clicked the element =" + currentID);
  ij += 1
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1">
  <div id="id2">
    <div id="id3">Click me</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do `return false;` or `e.stopPropagation();` in function end and use `var currentID = $(this).attr('id');` for fetch id

```js
var ij=1
$(document).on('click','div', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var currentID = $(this).attr('id'); 
    console.log("ij="+ij+" You clicked the element ="+currentID);
    ij+=1;
  return false;
});
```

```css
div{
padding:20px;
}

#d1{
background-color: red;
}

#id2{
background-color: blue;
}

#id3{
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d1">
    <div id="id2">
        <div id="id3">Click me</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `this.id` is valid JavaScript. No need to wrap it in a jQuery object.

Comment: OP has binded event with jQuery .

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm not saying `$(this).attr('id')` is false, I'm just saying that it's unnecessary. It does not matter what lib is used for the event binding, as long as `this` refers to the DOM element, there's no *need* to use JQuery if OP is fine with vanilla JS. You can see that it works with `this.id` in Satpal's answer.

Comment: ahh.. okk.. you are right.. :) but best practice is if we follow either jQuery methods or core JavaScript methods .. thats why I have used jQuery methods